# Cannot install my created packages

Tags: r, package, installation, devtools

I've been writing a lot of code for my personal use and finally reached a point where I realised I should really be including this all in a package which I can load in instead of copy and pasting it in each time.

I followed the following tutorial for the creation of a basic package.

https://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/

As far as I can tell everything went well with the actual creation element. Here are screenshots of the result:

The cats folder:

[image: 1]

The /cats/R folder

[image: 2]

The /cats/man folder

[image: 3]

The problem comes when I want to run the line:

```
install("cats")
```

When I try to do that I get the following error:

```
Installing cats
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL "/Documents/cats" --library="C:/Users/Aodhán/Documents/R/win-library/3.3" --install-tests 

 * installing *source* package 'cats' ...

 Warning in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") :

  cannot open file 'C:/Users/Aodhán/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/cats/DESCRIPTION': No such file or directory

 Error in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") : 

 cannot open the connection

 ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'cats'

 * removing 'C:/Users/Aodhán/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/cats'

 Error: Command failed (1)
```

This error happens for my own package, but it also happens if I run the command:

```
devtools::install_github("klutometis/roxygen")
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

EDIT: Could it be that my username contains the character á in it?

EDIT 2:The DESCRIPTION file is:

> Package: cats
>
> Title: What the Package Does (one line, title case)
>
> Version: 0.0.0.9000
>
> Authors@R: person("First", "Last", email = "first.last@example.com",
>   role = c("aut", "cre"))
>
> Maintainer: Aodhán O'Leary
>
> Author: Aodhán O'Leary [aut, cre]
>
> Description: What the package does (one paragraph).
>
> Depends: R (>= 3.3.1)
>
> License: What license is it under?
>
> Encoding: UTF-8
>
> LazyData: true
>
> RoxygenNote: 6.0.1

`Sys.getenv("R_HOME")` returns "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1"

`Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER")` returns "C:\Users\Aodhán\Documents/R/win-library/3.3"

`Sys.getenv("R_HOME")` returns "C:\Users\Aodhán\Documents"

`devtools::build("cats")` creates "cats_0.0.0.9000.tar.gz"

`install.packages("../cats_version.tar.gz")` returns the same error as above

Note: This is on a Win10 machine, using R 3.3.1, which I apologise for not mentioning up top. I was quite tired when writing the post yesterday.

Edit 3: Here's the result of using the following commands: `R CMD build cats` followed by `R CMD check cats`

00check:

> - using log directory 'C:/Users/Aodhán/Documents/cats.Rcheck'
> - using R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
> - using platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32 (64-bit)
> - using session charset: ISO8859-1
> - checking for file 'cats/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
> - this is package 'cats' version '0.0.0.9000'
> - package encoding: UTF-8
> - checking package namespace information ... OK
> - checking package dependencies ... OK
> - checking if this is a source package ... OK
> - checking if there is a namespace ... OK
> - checking for .dll and .exe files ... OK
> - checking for hidden files and directories ... NOTE Found the following hidden files and directories:   .gitignore These were most
>     likely included in error. See section 'Package structure' in the
>     'Writing R Extensions' manual.
> - checking for portable file names ... OK
> - checking whether package 'cats' can be installed ... ERROR Installation failed. See
>     'C:/Users/Aodhán/Documents/cats.Rcheck/00install.out' for details.
> - DONE
>
> Status: 1 ERROR, 1 NOTE

00install.out

> - installing *source* package 'cats' ...
>
> Warning in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") :
>         cannot open file 'C:/Users/Aodhan/Documents/cats.Rcheck/cats/DESCRIPTION':
>
> No such file or directory
>
> Error in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") : 
>         cannot open the connection
>
> ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'cats'
>
> - removing 'C:/Users/Aodhán/Documents/cats.Rcheck/cats'

Comment: Do all of these work as you expect? `Sys.getenv("USER")` and `dir.exists("~/Documents/R/win-library/3.3")`. Also, please include the output from `getwd()` and the path of your package directory. (I'm grasping here, no strong theory on what the problem might be.)

Comment: `Sys.getenv("USERNAME")` returns my username, `dir.exists(paste0(getwd(),"/R/win-library/3.3")` returns true and `getwd()` returns the path to the Documents folder. It is a strange one.

Comment: What does your description file look like?

Comment: I meant `Sys.getenv("USER")`, because the error references `%USER%`, not `%USERNAME%`. Is `~/Documents/cats/` the directory containing `DESCRIPTION` and `R/`?

Comment: Further env vars, what are `R_HOME`, `R_LIBS_USER`, and `R_USER`?

Comment: Are you able to do `devtools::build("cats")` and then `install.packages("../cats_version.tar.gz")`? (replace version with the right number)

Comment: `devtools::build("cats")` works, but the second command gives the same error as before. I'll edit the OP to reflect this and answer the other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the special character in my name, á. When I put it in the C:\ directory and ran `R CMD build cats` and `R CMD check cats` it passed that error (though there was an error later on with the pdf - I'll see if I can resolve that myself).

I'll try and post this as a bug. Moderately annoying. Should have thought of that test earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problem recently (R version 3.5.2) on two different computers. I don't have the full, exact error message right now, but it contained the following two snippets:

```
Error in writeLines(paste0(c(out[is_not_empty]), eor), file, useBytes = useBytes) :
(converted from warning) invalid char string in output conversion
```

and

```
ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package
```

The problem, I believe, was the existence of special characters in my `.Rprofile` file. I'd been meaning to get rid of that file anyway (for the sake of reproducibility), and doing so fixed the problem.

To do this in R, the code below will **(1)** copy your `.Rprofile` and save it as `.Rprofile-old` (in case you want to use/restore it later on) and then **(2)** delete your `.Rprofile`.

```
## copy backup of .Rprofile
file.copy("~/.Rprofile", "~/.Rprofile-old")

## delete .Rprofile
unlink("~/.Rprofile")
```

Once you've run the above code, restart R and the problem will [hopefully] be fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Installing source package..
It is important to specify repo and type

- **Convert package into package_name.tar.gz**
- Get  into project environment by double clicking the .Rproj file in
  your project and click on build -> Build Source Package to build tar.gz file
- **install.packages("full_path/package_name.tar.gz", repo = NULL, type =
  "source")**

Comment: He's using `devtools::install`, not `install.packages`, so the `repo` and `type` arguments are not used.