# Error installing package from github R

Tags: r, github, package

I am trying to install a package (l1ou) from [github](https://github.com/khabbazian/l1ou) but an error occurs every time. I am surprised, since I did the same yesterday and it worked well. I installed Rtools, updated R and additional packages, but I stil can't install this package. I've never seen this erros before, and trying solutions from previous posts didn't work as well. Also, I tried to instal from the .tar/.zip files, and it doesn't work.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("khabbazian/l1ou")

 * installing *source* package 'l1ou' ...
Warning in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/R/win-
library/3.3/l1ou/DESCRIPTION': No such file or directory
Error in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") : 
 cannot open the connection
ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'l1ou'
* removing 'C:/Users/Usuário/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/l1ou'
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
```

Then I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740256/error-installing-packages-from-github) suggestion:

```
library(httr)
 set_config(use_proxy(url="http://proxyname.company.com",port=8080,
username="XXX",password="XXX"))
install_github("khabbazian/l1ou")
Installation failed: Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10000 
milliseconds
```

Does anyone have any clue on that?
I really appreaciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this exchange](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-Help-Error-in-file-file-ifelse-append-quot-a-quot-quot-w-quot-No-connection-td4685416.html), I'm wondering if it has to do with your username, specifically the á. In the first step it returns `C:/Users/Usuario`, while the last it returns `C:/Users/Usuário`.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42678808/cannot-install-my-created-packages) also suggests the same, and looks like a bug.